Github actions: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching
I am using github actions along with fastlane to run my ci/cd pipeline to build and deploy ios build to app store. I am able to run the same fastlane "lane" on my M1 macbook air perfectly without any issues but i am not able to run the same in the CI environment and i am facing this error
Clean Succeeded
Error: No profile for team 'A******G' matching 'match Development com.myexample.app' found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching 'A********G/match Development com.myexample.app'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the Signing & Capabilities tab of the target editor. (in target 'RenoPartnerStage' from project 'RenoMerchant')
warning: Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'RenoPartnerStage' from project 'RenoMerchant')
warning: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'RenoPartnerStage' from project 'RenoMerchant')
Warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RNFB] Core Configuration' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'RenoPartnerStage' from project 'RenoMerchant')
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[08:39:20]: Exit status: 65

I cannot drag and drop it on to xcode as the error suggests. since it's in a CI environment.
Here's my fastlane file:
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc 'Fetch certificates and provisioning profiles'
  lane :certificates do
    match(app_identifier: 'com.ex.app', type: 'appstore')
    match(app_identifier: 'com.ex.myappprod', type: 'appstore')
  end


  desc "Push build"
  lane :push do
    sh "git status"
    version = get_version_number(xcodeproj: "RenoMerchant.xcodeproj", target: "RenoPartnerStage")
    build = get_build_number(xcodeproj: "RenoMerchant.xcodeproj")
    sh "git checkout -b ios/" + version + "/" +  build
    git_commit(path: ["../**.plist", "**/*.plist", "**/project.pbxproj"], message: "ios Version Bump to: " + version + " " + build)
    add_git_tag(tag: "ios-" + version + "-" +  build)
    push_to_git_remote
  end

  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    setup_ci
    increment_version_number(
      version_number: File.read("../../version/ios.version")
    )
    increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "RenoMerchant.xcodeproj")
    certificates
    build_app(
      workspace: "RenoMerchant.xcworkspace",
      scheme: "RenoPartnerStage",
      clean: true,
      export_method: "app-store",
      build_path: "./builds",
      output_directory: "./builds"
    )
    upload_to_testflight(
      skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true
    )
    push
  end


Here's my github CD workflow
name: Build and deploy iOS Beta
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  staging-build:
    name: iOS-beta-build
    runs-on: macos-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [20.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      - name: Checkout to git repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Xcode
        uses: maxim-lobanov/setup-xcode@v1
        with:
          xcode-version: latest-stable

      - name: Install Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 3.2.2

      - name: Install Fastlane
        run: |
          gem install fastlane

      - name: Install npm dependencies
        run: |
          npm install

      - name: Configure Git
        run: |
          git config --global user.email 'email@mydomain.com'
          git config --global user.name 'Github-actions-ios'
          echo '${{ secrets.MATCH_PRIVATE_SSH_KEY }}' | cat >> ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
          eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
          echo '${{ secrets.SSH_CONFIG_FILE }}' | cat >> ~/.ssh/config
          chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

      - name: Cache Pods
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        id: pods-cache
        with:
          path: ./ios/Pods
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-pods-${{ hashFiles('ios/Podfile.lock') }}

      - name: Install pods
        run: |
          cd ios
          RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 pod install --repo-update
          cd ..

      - name: Build and upload to TestFlight
        env:
          MATCH_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MATCH_PASSWORD }}
          FASTLANE_USER: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_USER }}
          FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD }}
          FASTLANE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_PASSWORD }}
          CI: 1
        run: |
          cd ios
          fastlane ios beta




What am i missing here, I am using match for managing my certificates and provisioning profiles, but still i am facing this issue.
